# How do i detect arrow keys in an mfc application?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How can i detect an arrow key when it's pressed? Is a particular message sent for each arrow key?

Comment: Where, in Dialog or on some control? Answer given by Rost is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [CWnd::OnKeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/983st27a.aspx) and [CWnd::OnKeyUp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yddt1ty6.aspx) handlers for `WM_KEYDOWN`/`WM_KEYUP` Windows messages and check `nChar` parameter for virtual key codes `VK_LEFT`, `VK_UP`, `VK_RIGHT`, `VK_DOWN`.